# Find method raise error 91 in excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I use a find method in the Excel macro for searching `VLOOKUP` in a cell, my goal is I need to know which formula that does not contain `VLOOKUP`, my method was running well, until in a cell there was
no `VLOOKUP` and macro kept debugging with the Run time error '91'

My question is how should I write the macro correctly so I wont get the debug until the activecell
contains `*`, below is my macro:

```
Sub findvlookup()

    Do While Not ActiveCell.Value = "*"

        If Selection.Find(What:="VLOOKUP", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: on what line does the error occur? (the yellow debug line)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to find the first occurrence of your 'What:=" string

```
Dim fndVL as Range

fndVL = Selection.Find(What:="VLOOKUP", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not fndVL is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Found it"
Else
   NsgBox "Not found"
End If
```

If you want to find subsequent instances then have a look at [FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143(v=office.15).aspx) and possibly use this within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub findvlookup()

Dim rngFind As Range

Do While Not ActiveCell.Value = "*"

    Set rngFind = Selection.Find(What:="VLOOKUP", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If



Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Find method that technical details are [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

You can find (in example) that:

> Common **Err.Numbers (9, 91)** : the specified text wasn't in the target workbook.

And if you have a cell with an error value you will have another type of errors: like `#Value`